# Error in C++ code: In function 'int main(int, char**)':

Tags: c++, file, oop, filestream

I am a newbie and a student of Computer Sciences. I am doing my assignment Which is spell checker of a text file. I have done the code but I am  getting the following errors. I am unable to resolve it. kindly help me guys. Thanks!

[image: Error Image]

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class spell_check
{
    private:
    int line_number=0;
    string input="" ;
    string dictionary="";
    bool condition=false;
    
    public:
    void process(int x,char *y[]);
};
void spell_check::process(int x,char *y[])
{
    ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open(y[2]);
    
    ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open(y[4]);
    while(!input_file.eof())
            {
                line_number++;
                getline(input_file,input);

                ifstream dictionary_file("dictionary.txt");
                while(!dictionary_file.eof())
                    {
                        getline(dictionary_file,dictionary);
                        if( input.compare(dictionary) == 0 )
                            {
                                condition=true;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                if(condition==false)
                    {
                        output_file<<"**Spell mistake** "<< "( " << input << ")"<< "[" <<"at line no: " << line_number <<"]"<<endl;
            
                    }
                dictionary_file.close();
                condition=false;
            }
                    cout<<"Successfully Write "<<endl;

    input_file.close();
    output_file.close();
}
int main(int argum,char *argu_array[])
{
    
        spell_check SC;
        SC.process(argum, *argu_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Class is required in assingment file.

Comment: Post the error as text, not images.

Comment: Its in c++ oop. So I tag it.

Comment: Try the line without the star: just `SC.process(argum, argu_array);`

Comment: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
54:32: error: no matching function for call to 'spell_check::process(int&, char*&)'
54:32: note: candidate is:
15:6: note: void spell_check::process(int, char**)
15:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'char*' to 'char**'

Comment: Error message has been added. Kinld check the quesiton again.

Comment: So the problem is here `SC.process(argum, *argu_array);` which should be `SC.process(argum, argu_array);`. Not sure why you added `*`, `argu_array` is already the same type as `check_process`

Comment: @Rup, Nothing happened without that line.

Comment: Looks like `SC.process(argum, argu_array);` should work.

Comment: I meant remove the star, not remove the line.

Comment: Let me try it..........

Comment: As compiler error messages go this is pretty straightforward. It's telling you that the type of the second parameter to `check_process` is wrong.

Comment: Its work. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Thanks to all. :)

Comment: @AmnaMughal Unfortunately as you're going to find out, there are other errors in your program.

Comment: @john, Which errors are there in program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error here:

```
int main(int argum,char *argu_array[])
{

        spell_check SC;
        SC.process(argum, *argu_array);

        return 0;
}
```

since the type of the second argument of the main function is char* []
and also the type of the argument of the process method is the same:

```
void spell_check::process(int x,char *y[])
```

you don't have to dereference it, try this:

```
SC.process(argum, argu_array);
```

Comment: thank you SeventhSon84. I have resovled it. :)